# Exchange Server 2016 Error MaxQueryStringLength when I try to open Admin Console

Tags: iis, exchange, exchange-2016

So I have a 2012 R2 server with Exchange 2016 installed on it. This server is a part of a DAG. Of the three servers in this DAG, only one of them, we'll call it server1, cannot get to the EAC. I can get to the EAC for server2 and server3 from server1 (as well as other servers in other DAGs for that matter), but I cannot get to the one that belongs to server1. The IIS error page I get says:

```
Server Error in '/ecp' Application (in big red letters)

The length of the query string for this request exceeds the configured maxQueryStringLength value
```

I've seen a couple of pages dealing with this, but it seems to be mostly from a programming standpoint. This would seem to be an IIS error and all the solutions to the link below involve making changes in either IIS Manager or to the web.config file directly.

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159321/request-exceeds-the-configured-maxquerystringlength-when-using-authorize)

I've found [this website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.maxquerystringlength(v=vs.110).aspx), which led me to [this website](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits), which show how to edit the specified property.

I've set it to the max value and it takes a really long time, but it still fails. It kind of leads me to believe that I'm barking up the wrong tree. Anybody seen this issue yet with Exchange 2016?

Comment: Which Exchange 2016 Patch level are you using?

Comment: CU3. The rest of my servers are also on CU3. Now I can't get to the EAC for any of the servers in this particular DAG, either from the servers themselves or from other Exchange servers in my organization. I can get to other EACs on this and other servers.

Comment: Hm, one idea might be to backup the SharedWebConfig.config and copy it over from a working one as explained [here](http://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/exchange/373-resolved-exchange-2016-iis-not-usable-after-installation-from-cu5.html) it wouldn´t harm as you can switch back if still needed, but might be an option to check if the solution in the link might fix your issue as well. By the way, for security reasons your REALLY should upgrade to a higher CU!

Comment: Hmmm, no love there either. The error described in the link is not real close to what my issue is, though they are both IIS related, it seems.

Comment: yes its not exactly the error but please try the solution there and check if its solving your issues or not.

Comment: Right, "no love there" was meant to convey that the solution (copy a SharedWebConfig.config file) did not work either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59159/discussion-between-bastianw-and-joseph).

Answer (score 0):

Check the IIS Bindings on server1 and other normal servers. Make sure the Bindings setting is correct on Default Web Site and Exchange Backend site.

Meanwhile, on server1, make sure the .NET CLR Version of MSExchangeECPAppPool is v4.0. If it is already v4.0, change it to v2.0, run IISReset, then change it back to v4.0. Run IISReset.

Comment: Hey Sue, thanks for your suggestion. Still no love, same error. The bindings look like they have the correct certificates and ports matched up, so as to say, they match what other servers have.

Comment: Oh... In this situation, I would recommend you upgrade this server to Exchange 2016 CU4 or CU5. As we know, upgrading would replace the configuration files and reinstall some components. That would help to resolve this issue.